# What is this plant with long thin leaves with red marks?

Tags: identification, herbs

[image]

I need help identifying what type of plant this is. I bought some seed for basil, oregano, parsley, etc. and this grew among them. I was wondering what it could be? I live near Toronto if that may help, if its a wild plant?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is one of the smartweeds, similar to Polygonum odoratum, (previously Persicaria odoratum), also known as Vietnamese coriander. Don't take that as gospel, it might be one of the other smartweeds, there's lots of them, but a drawing of P. odoratum showing stem arrangement and the marking on the leaves here
https://www.123rf.com/photo_31927479_vietnamese-coriander-polygonum-odoratum-or-persicaria-odoratum.html

Comment: My plants seems very like the one of Alexandru, but for sure it is not (my plant) a  _Polygonum_. Flowers are totally different.

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems an asparagus lettuce. I got the seeds from a friend. But googling, it seems not very like the celtuce.  On the other hand, when growing, I see the form of asparagus in this lettuce.

I'm alive, so it is edible, and I think some seeds for nearby cultivation mixed with the regular one.

Comment: I think you're right because I did plant asparagus seed mixed in there, but the asparagus is growing normally for the most part so maybe they included some asparagus lettuce as well, unless its supposed to grow together? I can't help but wonder why the plant has some reddish hues and some darker areas. Would anyone happen to know?

Comment: This looks similar (Chinese celtuce, purple sword): http://www.agrohaitai.com/rootstem/celtuce/purple_sword.htm

Comment: @Alexandru: my are also so reddish (leaves and stem). I'm sure we have the same plant, possibly not the most common variety of asparagus lettuce. Note asparagus lettuce is a variety of lettuce, nothing to do (botanically) with asparagus (but the form and the way to eat them, when they are sprouting.